# Stop programs and games from opening by default on secondary monitor?

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, games

I have a two monitor setup, one DVI (secondary) and one HDMI (main). My main monitor is in front of me and runs in 1080p, while my secondary is to the left and only runs in 900p. A common problem I've had is that some programs, windows, and even games will open on that monitor. In the event of a game, it will often be stretched and skewed because of the resolution difference.

The biggest offender to this was Dead Island, which would appear halfway "up" the screen. The only workaround was to have a window open on my primary monitor then open a game or program, or drag the window from the secondary to the primary.

My main monitor is selected as the primary both in my Nvidia settings and my display settings. What am I doing wrong?